# Filtering multiple classes with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I've created a Multiple Checkbox Filter where there are 2 filter options: Gender and State

What I want to achieve is:

Filter the elements that have AT LEAST one of the STATE categories, but as soon as the GENDER is checked, hide the elements that are not from that gender

So for example, I am filtering by standing AND walking (this shows all female and male standing and walking), but as soon as I check MALE, this has to hide all females, so it'll show all male standing and walking.

```js
function run() {
    $(".item").hide();
    const checked = $(":checked");
    var gender = $("[name='gender']:checked").val();
    var state = $("[name='state']:checked").val();
    
    if (checked.length === 0) {
        return $(".item").show();
    }
    checked.each(function() {
        //$(".item." + this.id).show(); //Works, but it doesn't hide the non checked gender
        return $(this).hasClass(gender) || $(".item." + this.state);
    }).show();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" onclick="run()" /> Male
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" onclick="run()" /> Female
</div>
<div id="state">
  <input type="checkbox" id="walking" name="state" onclick="run()" /> Walking
  <input type="checkbox" id="standing" name="state" onclick="run()" /> Standing
</div>

<br/>
<div class="item male walking" >male walking</div>
<div class="item male standing walking">male standing and walking</div>
<div class="item standing female walking">female standing and walking</div>
<div class="item female walking">female walking</div>
```

Comment: If you have male checked, is `male+female standing` supposed to show?

Comment: Ok then see answer below

Comment: i would think if male and female are checked, if should only show item with male AND female instead of OR

Comment: if both the male and female are checked, do you show the male + female item, or do you show the items that are either male or female?

Comment: @Mika then `but as soon as I check MALE, this has to hide all females, so it'll show all male standing and walking.` won't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: gather the checked items, and for each of them query the DOM for their names and show them.

Note that this is fairly inefficient because you are querying the DOM multiple times for the same elements. You should ideally save the elements collections and just call show/hide them when needed.

Also, note that I added the labels to improve the UX of your input elements. Now you can click on the labels themselves to check the inputs.

---

**Edit:** If inputs are supposed to be mutually exclusive, a radio buttons is a better fit. I have changed the UI to use radio buttons and added a box to reset the button (do not filter for gender). I am not sure how the male+female is supposed to work. At the moment, it is not included in neither gender.

```js
function run() {
  $(".item").hide();
  let opposingGender = '';
  $(":checked").each(function() {
    let selector = '.' + this.value;
    if (this.name === 'gender') {
      opposingGender = ':not(.' + (this.value === 'male' ? 'female' : 'male') +')';
    }
    selector += opposingGender;
    $(selector).show();
  });
};

function unselect() {
  $('[name=gender]').prop('checked', false);
  run();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">
  <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="gender" onclick="run()" /> <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" value="female" name="gender" onclick="run()" /> <label for="female">Female</label>
  <button onclick="unselect()">Unselect</button>
</div>
<div id="state">
  <input type="checkbox" id="walking" value="walking" name="state" onclick="run()" /> <label for="walking">Walking</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="standing" value="standing" name="state" onclick="run()" /> <label for="standing">Standing</label>
</div>

<br/>
<div class="item male walking" >male walking</div>
<div class="item male standing walking">male standing and walking</div>
<div class="item standing female walking">female standing and walking</div>
<div class="item female walking">female walking</div>
<div class="item male female standing">male+female standing</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But as soon as the gender is checked, it should hide the other gender. So if male is checked, it should hide the females. This wouldn't happen with the STATE, they can have either or both of the categories

Answer (score 1):

Logic has been updated to show male OR female using radio buttons instead of select. All inline click handlers has been removed and updated to use the change handler

```js
var genderSelector = "";
var stateSelector = "";

var filter = function() {
  var selector = stateSelector + genderSelector;

  if (selector) {
    $(".item").hide();
    $(stateSelector + genderSelector).show();
    //console.log(stateSelector + genderSelector);
  } else {
    $(".item").show();
  }
};

$("#gender input").change(function() {
  genderSelector = this.value == "male" ? ".male:not(.female)" : ".female:not(.male)";
  filter();
});

$("#state input").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    stateSelector = stateSelector + "." + this.id;
  } else {
    stateSelector = stateSelector.replace("." + this.id, "");
  }
  filter();
});


// this runs on load so the initial view will be pdated
genderSelector = $("#gender :checked").val() == "male" ? ".male:not(.female)" : ".female:not(.male)";
filter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">
  <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="gender" checked /> Male
  <input type="radio" id="female" value="female" name="gender" /> Female
</div>
<div id="state">
  <input type="checkbox" id="walking" name="state" /> Walking
  <input type="checkbox" id="standing" name="state" /> Standing
</div>

<br/>
<div class="item male walking">male walking</div>
<div class="item male standing walking">male standing and walking</div>
<div class="item standing female walking">female standing and walking</div>
<div class="item female walking">female walking</div>
<div class="item male female standing">male+female standing</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if standing and walking are checked, it should show all items with either one of the two categories checked or both of them. In this case it should show all items, because they all have at least one of these categories

Comment: @Mika I think you need clarify the filtering logic, and show which 2 items are AND relationship and which are OR. I asked you if male is checked, if male + female standing should show and you said yes but in the question itself you said if male is checked and female shouldn't show, are these conflicting?

Comment: @mika if they are both ORs then when you check male item, female items will show too which is in direct conflict with your ask of `but as soon as I check MALE, this has to hide all females, so it'll show all male standing and walking.` `male+female standing` will show when male OR female OR standing is checked

Comment: You're right, sorry for the misunderstanding. So when male is checked, male+female should be hidden. The STATE would be AND and the GENDER would be OR

Comment: I still think your filtering logic has issues, if male+female hides when male is clicked then the same logic would follow that when female is clicked then males should be hidden, now what if both male and female are clicked? following the previous logic then both should be hidden but male + female item should be shown instead

Comment: Yes, let's do something. Remove the male+female and just work with either one gender and the state (it can have either one or both)

Comment: Yes that's the better approach, you should change male and female into radio buttons since it is one or the other, checkboxes gives the wrong idea.

Comment: I was doing that already, thanks! So, following this new logic... do you know how can we do this?

Comment: Not 100% done yet but you can test the logic by first selecting male or female and then the checkedboxes, the change will currently trigger when you click on the checkboxes

Comment: Try it now and see if the logics works, you would put this code block on document ready, I removed the inline onclicks. The code can be optimized a bit by caching some stuff but you get the idea